# Calculating Rolling P&L of Trade Log

Tags: programming, backtesting, pnl

I have an extensive trade log of historical buy and sell orders and I am trying to calculate the running p&l of the trading results. Most rows represent partial fills where there is still a balance of the traded asset held between time periods. This is confusing me a bit, as it seems there needs to be a rolling cost basis included in the calculation, although I am not 100% sure.

My preferable output would be a cumulative percent profit/loss throughout the history as its own column.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Hypothetical starting balance: $1,000

| datetime | qty_purchased | price_paid | total_held |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | -123.6859 | 8.0700 | -123.6859 |
| 2017-01-01 00:15:00 | 30.7804 | 8.1522 | -92.9055 |
| 2017-01-01 00:30:00 | 55.4980 | 8.2000 | -37.4075 |
| 2017-01-01 01:15:00 | 1.0060 | 8.2697 | -36.4015 |
| 2017-01-01 02:15:00 | -86.7758 | 8.2249 | -123.1773 |
| 2017-01-01 02:30:00 | 10.5669 | 8.4200 | -112.6104 |
| 2017-01-01 03:00:00 | 70.6846 | 8.4800 | -41.9258 |
| 2017-01-01 03:15:00 | -81.2236 | 8.4602 | -123.1494 |
| 2017-01-01 03:30:00 | 112.2577 | 8.5316 | -10.8917 |

Comment: How about adding the following columns: Qty_held which is the cumulative sum of qty_purchased, cash in/out which is -qty_purchased×price_paid, cash_balance which starts at 1000 and cumulatively sums cash in/out, stock mark2market which is qty_held×price_paid and finally total wealth which is the sum of cash balance and stock mark2market columns.

Comment: Thanks @noob2 - I just tried it and that looks good to me. Greatly appreciate the help and input.